# Zurb Foundation 5 - Flush on mobile

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am very new to zurb. What I want to do is have a grid layout where on mobile the grid is flush to the screen. But then on "big web" there is padding either side. For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 large-centered columns">6 centered</div>
</div>
```

Will give me column in the middle on big web, but when I shrink down the div is not flush.

What I am trying to achieve is this:
Have a mobile app sized page that when expanded all of the elements get bigger for big web and are centred in their div in the middle of the page for example 1/3. 1/3. 1/3

What is the best strategy in Zurb for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: [your mobile breakpoint width]) {
    .row, .column, .columns {
        padding-left: 0; 
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you may not need the mobile breakpoint width. just override padding (and also margins) like this:  http://cdpn.io/jfLoy